# java: create and submit form from servlet and move to the target url

Tags: java, forms, servlets

One of the webservices I am trying to connect requires me to submit a form to an url, lets say LINK_A.

I have a form view VIEW_A, I submit VIEW_A to my own servlet called SERVLET_A. Here in SERVLET_A from the form params, I generate a signature key, which is required by the webservice.

Then I need to submit to LINK_A programmaticaly from my servlet, BUT they told me that I need to submit it and redirects to LINK_A, so unlike what I've known so far (using httpclient httppost and getting the response data), I need to do something like a redirect with post data to their link.

So in summary:
 1. from my view, submit a form
 2. modify post data from servlet
 3. submit the form to the webservice link and move to that link (as if the form from the view submit directly to the webservice link)

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the form to be submitted from the browser (not from within your servlet using httpclient) your servlet needs to return a self-submitting form. E.g. use `document.getElementById('myForm').submit()` on `documentReady`.

If your form params can be submitted via `GET` you might also respond with a HTTP 302 redirect containing all params in the query string.

Comment: thanks sir. i was actually searching for a java method but I cant find one so i'll take this as this works out great.

Comment: there is no server-side method to redirect a client to another page and include POST data. HTTP does not support such a thing, thats why a java-only solution won't work ;)

Answer (score 0):

mean if you want collect request from previous form and check in servlet class and forward to new form den check this logic if its help

form code within servlet

```
rotected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html body=\"red\"> <center>");
        pw.println("<form action=\"./NewFile.do\" method=\"get\">");
        pw.println("<h2>enter the name </h2> <input type=\"text\" name=\"username\">");
        pw.println("<h2>enter the password </h2> <input type=\"text\" name=\"passward\">");
        pw.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"login\">");

        pw.println("</form>");
        pw.println("<center></body></html> ");



    }
```

this below code to check and initialize path, before that you have to configure web.xml for this servlet class to behave as controller.

```
public class ServletControl extends HttpServlet {
        @Override
        protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("inside the servlet");
            String servletpath=request.getServletPath();
            String path = null;
            if(servletpath.equalsIgnoreCase("/NewFile.do")){
                path="NewFile.jsp";
            }
    if(path!=null){
                RequestDispatcher dis=request.getRequestDispatcher(path);
                dis.forward(request, response);
            }
    }
    }
```

Comment: @Sebastian S, thanks for your guidance to this answer.